# Two-way binding cannot resolve a setter for java.lang.String property

Tags: android, android-databinding, two-way

I am playing with the two-way binding of the data binding API which was introduced in Android Studio 2.1 AFIK.

I get this interesting error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   > java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:The expression address.street cannot cannot be inverted: Two-way binding cannot resolve a setter for java.lang.String property 'street'
>   file:/path/to/layout.xml
>   loc:34:37 - 34:50
>   ****\ data binding error ****

When I try to google that error I just find a 4 day old Japanese Twitter posting from a guy who is crying about it...

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_hint_zip"
    android:text="@={address.zip}"
    tools:text="12345"/>
```

That `address.zip` is a `String`. I am guessing that the problem here is `CharSequence` vs. `String` as the return value of `EditText.getText()`.

My idea was to defining it however this does not work for me:

```
@NonNull
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "text")
public static String getText(EditText edit) {
    return edit.getText().toString();
}
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This bug is ugly as hell and properly a bug in the data binding API. The solution is to generate a setter *and a **getter***. I came up fast with the idea to create a setter, but not to create a getter.

Here is now my simplified model:

```
public class Address {
    public String street;

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }
}
```

As you may note the getter and setter are useless, but required for two way binding.

If you think that this is a bug of the API please star my bug report: [Two-way binding required setters AND ALSO getters](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=208640)

Answer (score 33):

If you are working with kotlin , make sure data class field used for two way binding is declared as var. If it is val unable to support two way binding

Comment: This worked for me, but cold you give additional information why data binding does not work on val properties

Comment: In Kotlin Val means static. Var means non-static. In databinding, the variable values may be changed so must declare as var.

Comment: In Kotlin `val` doesn't mean static it means final. 
I think speaking from a two way binding perspective, it does make sense to have your class properties declared as var because, you do want their properties to change.

Answer (score 0):

According to databinding offical repo https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/ commit message, this bug has been fixed at Android Studio 2.2 preview 3.

Comment: Can you link the commit you are talking about? I see there just one commit which was pushed 8 weeks ago, which seems not to been related.

Comment: Do you mean the commit [0137f2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/0137f239576702ac3ef4dd887b445d71f35169dd)?

Comment: Yes, and I also tested on different versions of Android Studio.